# Two time variables, determine if the second time is on the next day

Tags: php, datetime

I only get one date, and two times (24 hour format).

Is there an elegant way of finding out if the second time goes into the next day?

Pseudocode:

```
$inputDate1 = "2020-12-27"
$inputHour1 = "21:00";

$inputHour2 = "00:10";
$calulatedDate2 = ???

$dateTime1 = $inputDate . " " . $inputHour1;
$dateTime2 = $calulatedDate2 . " " . $inputHour1;
```

Other examples:

08:00 and 12:00 would be same date.

08:00 and 07:59 would be next date.

Comment: Can you just check if the second time is before or after the first one? That's very straightforward to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the time is less than the input1.

```
$inputDate1 = "2020-12-27";
$inputHour1 = "21:00";

$inputHour2 = "00:10";

if(strtotime($inputHour2) < strtotime($inputHour1)){
    $calulatedDate2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($inputDate1)+86400);
}else{
    $calulatedDate2 = $inputDate1;
}

$dateTime1 = $inputDate1 . " " . $inputHour1;
$dateTime2 = $calulatedDate2 . " " . $inputHour2;

Var_dump($dateTime1, $dateTime2);
```

https://3v4l.org/kH6CV

Comment: Haha, you beat me by 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I found one way to do it. Feel free to post more elegant solutions.

```
$inputDate1 = "2020-12-27"
$inputHour1 = "21:00";

$inputHour2 = "00:10";
$inputDate2 = $inputDate1 //just assume for now

$dateTime1 = $inputDate1 . " " . $inputHour1;
$dateTime2 = $inputDate2 . " " . $inputHour1;

      
if (strtotime($dateTime2) < strtotime($dateTime1)) {
    $dateTime2 = (DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $dateTime2))->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    }
```